# people method is not working in pickerchildren.get.js Alfresco Community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Using alfresco community 5.0.d.

I am suddenly getting below error for people methods in pickerchildren.get.js file.

```
Can't find method org.alfresco.repo.jscript.People.getContainerGroups(org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined). (classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerchildren.get.js#366)
```

Error in console:

```
{
"status": {
"code": 500,
"name": "Internal Error",
"description": "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
},
"message": "Can't find method org.alfresco.repo.jscript.People.getContainerGroups(org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined). (classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerchildren.get.js#366)",
"exception": "",
"callstack": [],
"server": "Community v5.0.0 (d r99759-b2) schema 8,022",
"time": "Mar 21, 2017 5:52:17 PM"
}
```

Where else in other part of the file people methods are working fine.

Below is code that I had added:

```
if (people.isAdmin(person)) {
    for each(var personRef in personRefs)
    {
        personObj = createPersonResult(search.findNode(personRef));
        // add to results
        results.push({
            item: personObj,
            selectable: true
        });
    }
    return;
}
```

It was working fine earlier but suddenly broke down.

> Also person is coming as undefined.

Any idea is apprepicated.
Thanks!

Comment: if possible then upload entire file.

Comment: Have you changed anything in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the error message that JavaScript is looking for a method getContainerGroups that accepts an undefined object.

Based on that, I suspect personObj is null. You should add a guard against adding null items to the results array and see if that helps.

Comment: Can't find method org.alfresco.repo.jscript.People.getContainerGroups(org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined). (classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerchildren.get.js#366)

Comment: It's giving error that it can't find Can't find method getContainerGroups or isAdmin method for people api

Comment: Where is this code running? Alfresco WAR or Share WAR?

Comment: Alfresco (Path: /Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerchildren.get.js)

Comment: Did you change anything else, such as the descriptor? Also, rather than change the out-of-the-box web script, which is a bad practice, you should at least copy the controller into your own package structure under extensions.

Comment: I'm doing changs out-of-box and now reverted back to last changes committed. Everything looks good now. Still wondering what caused that issue. (Difference was just in single method that I was overriding)